# Is it possible to create a custom toolbar for the Windows XP taskbar?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, taskbar, toolbar

[image]

I want to add a tool/utility to the Windows XP taskbar where the white space is in the above screenshot, so that I can insert some text.

Is this possible? How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to write a explorer band object. Check out this manual: 
[codeproject.com](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/dotnetbandobjects.aspx)